# How can I upload a 'secret file' via the Azure DevOps REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

There is a secure file store built into Azure DevOps, available here: [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_library?itemType=SecureFiles](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_library?itemType=SecureFiles)

I want to upload a file into that secure storage from a pipeline (because the file is generated by the pipeline). I understand that currently there is no dedicated task type to do this, so I have to do it via the Azure DevOps REST API.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This bash scripts seems to be working for me:

```
set -e

name="my-file"
token="$(System.AccessToken)"
base_url="https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis"
local_file="/path/to/local/file"

echo "Check if secure file $name exists"
existing_id="$(curl --fail -s -L -u ":${token}" "${base_url}/distributedtask/securefiles?api-version=5.0-preview.1" | jq -r ".value[] | select(.name == \"$name\").id " )"

if [ -n "$existing_id" ]; then
  echo "Delete existing secure file: $existing_id"
  curl --fail -v -L -X DELETE -u ":${token}" "${base_url}/distributedtask/securefiles/$existing_id?api-version=5.0-preview.1"
fi
echo "Uploading secure file as: $name"
curl --data-raw "@${local_file}" -u ":${token}" --fail -v -L -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" "${base_url}/distributedtask/securefiles?api-version=5.0-preview.1&name=${name}"
```

NOTE: I've used the API call examples that I've found here: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10072318/SzfAyS4s#3f75659d-4461-4efe-9ba3-77d5112f0bbe

Comment: I expect the official documentation to appear somewhere here in the future: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Comment: Thanks for the post. I have not tried it but plan on doing so soon. Did you happen to find out if the newly uploaded file becomes available directly after running your upload script? Or are the secure files getting cached/fixed at the *beginning* of each pipeline run, i.e. the newly uploaded file will only become available in the next run of the pipeline?